# JQuery focus an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

In javascript the following works to give focus to the edit_2 input box:

```
document.getElementById("edit_2").focus();
```

However using Jquery this does not:

```
$("#edit_2").focus;
```

Comment: Its an old Article, but already open for answers ... answers should be deactivated.... 
My Answer would be (also 2010) read the jQuery Docs ;) greetings

Comment: Old question, but reading the documentation doesn't help if it doesn't click...

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You are calling a method, so:

```
$("#edit_2").focus;
```

should be

```
$("#edit_2").focus();
```

**EDIT**: If you are wondering why the first line was not counted as a syntax error, it's because it is a correct statement saying "get the function `focus`" (and do nothing with it).

Answer (score 15):

Your statement

```
$("#edit_2").focus
```

is not calling the function 'focus', in order to call the function you have to use the syntax 'focus()'

try

```
j$("#some_id").focus()
```

It is working fine.

**EDIT**
Your statement '$("#edit_2").focus' is not throwing an error because it just returns a reference to the function 'focus', but it does not call the function.

Answer (score 10):

`focus` is a function and must be called like one, change your code to look like:

```
$("#edit_2").focus();
```

For reference, see [focus documentation](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).